# When an object's state changes another object's state changes also in react native redux

Tags: react-native, redux

I am trying to hold user info with defaultUser as default state after fetching. But If user state changes with UPDATEUSERSTATE, defaultUser also changes. I could not understand that behaivour

1. Firstly fetching the data from restApi
2. Updating user state on MainComponent
3. If User changes textinput on ModalView, updating the user state.

   ```js
         const userReducer = (state = {} ,action) => {
         switch (action.type) {
         case actionTypes.GETUSERINFOBYUSERNAME_SUCCESS:
              return {
                       ...state,
                       isFetching: action.isFetching,
                       error: action.error,
                       user: action.user,
                       defaultUser:action.user,
                       open: true
                   };
        case actionTypes.UPDATEUSERSTATE:
                 return {
                   ...state,          
                   user: action.user         
                 }
         default:
               console.log("[userReducer]: defalt state");
               return state;      
         }            
       };    
   //ACTIONS
    export const getUserInfoByUserNameSuccess=(user) => {
           return {type: actionTypes.GETUSERINFOBYUSERNAME_SUCCESS, isFetching: true, error: null, user: user}
       }    
       export const updateUserState=(user) => {
           return {type: actionTypes.UPDATEUSERSTATE, user:user}
       }    
   //CALLING GETUSERINFO
    this.props.onGetUserInfoByUserName(val);    
   const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
         return{
             onGetUserInfoByUserName : userName => dispatch(getUserInfoByUserNameFetching(userName))
         };
       };
   //AND CALLING UPDATEUSERSTATE
   textChangedHandler = (key,value) => {
        let user = this.props.user;
        user[key]=value;
       this.props.onUpdateUserState(user);
       }    
    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
              return{
               onUpdateUserState : (user) => dispatch(updateUserState(user))
           };
         };
   ```

Comment: could you console log the return in `UPDATEUSERSTATE` and really check if it changes?

Comment: Yes, I checked that. user and defaultUser is on same state when UPDATEUSERSTATE runs.

Comment: Can you show the actions that you are calling? And can you show where in code that you are calling the actions from?

Comment: You should not post code as comments, please edit your question and paste the code in there.

Comment: Thank you for warning. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're directly setting the values of two separate objects to reference the same object (both `user` and `defaultUser` are being set to reference object `action.user`). So if you change the value of one of the objects, the reference changes which changes the second object.

Redux doesn't replace the object with a new one, but rather does a shallow copy of the new values. See the below snippet for an example:

```js
var actionUser = { foo: 1 }
var defaultUser = actionUser
var user = actionUser

user.bar = 2

console.log(actionUser)
// { foo: 1, bar: 2 }

console.log(defaultUser)
// { foo: 1, bar: 2 }

console.log(user)
// { foo: 1, bar: 2 }
```

To fix this you can use the `Object.assign()` method to assign the references to a new object. See below snippet:

```js
var actionUser = { foo: 1 }
var defaultUser = Object.assign({}, actionUser)
var user = Object.assign({}, actionUser)

user.bar = 2

console.log(actionUser)
// { foo: 1 }

console.log(defaultUser)
// { foo: 1 }

console.log(user)
// { foo: 1, bar: 2 }
```

So whenever you assign a new value from your actions to any of your state objects, use `Object.assign()`.

Example (from your code):

```js
case actionTypes.GETUSERINFOBYUSERNAME_SUCCESS:
           return {
                    ...state,
                    user: Object.assign({}, action.user),
                    defaultUser: Object.assign({}, action.user),
                };
case actionTypes.UPDATEUSERSTATE:
           return {
                ...state,          
                user: Object.assign({}, action.user),       
              }
```

Comment: I was littlebit about Object.assign. It is realy clear now. many thanks for detailed explanation.

Comment: It's a pleasure!